# ¿porque este programa no funciona?

Tags: c++

Se supone que `typeat template` debe devolver el `type` de entre
Los difentes `types` incluidos en un `container` llamado `Cons`

Es del libro *advanced metaprogramming g++ v4.9 tdm windows*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template < typename T1, typename T2 >
struct typepair { typedef T1 head_t; typedef T2 tail_t; }; 
struct empty { };
struct Error_UNDEFINED_TYPE; // no definition!


template < size_t N, typename CONTAINER, typename ERR = Error_UNDEFINED_TYPE
>
struct typeat
{ 
typedef ERR type;

};

template<typename T1,typename T2,typename ERR>
struct typeat < 0, typepair < T1, T2 >, ERR > 
{
typedef T1 type; 
};

template < size_t N, typename T1, typename T2, typename ERR >
struct typeat < N, typepair < T1, T2 >, ERR >
{
 typedef typename typeat < N-1, T2, ERR >::type type; 
};
template <  size_t N,typename ERR >
struct typeat < N, empty, ERR >
{ 
typedef empty type;
};




template < typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Args >
struct cons 
{ 
typedef typepair < T1, typepair < T2, Args...  > > type; 
};
int main(int argc,char **argv){

typedef  cons<float,float,int,empty> mio_t; 
typedef  typename  typeat<1,cons<float,float,int,empty>>::type final;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_floating_point<final>::value << 
std::endl;
//CONTROL ERRORES
std::cout << std::boolalpha << 
std::is_same<final,Error_UNDEFINED_TYPE>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<final,empty>::value << 
std::endl;

return 0;
};
```

Comment: Hola FJsanto, bienvenido. Puedes quitar las mayusculas? En internet significa estar gritando .Un saludo

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Al igual que @lois6b te sugiero que sustituyas las mayúsculas por minúsculas. Por otro lado ¿Cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: ¿CUÁL ES EL ERROR QUE ESTÁS RECIBIENDO?... perdón, ¿Qué error estás recibiendo al usar el código que has pegado?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, es eso acaso sarcasmo?, jejejeje

Comment: el error es que sistematicamente devuelve false  salvo en Error_UNDEFINED_TYPE que por los visto es el tipo reportado.Gracias por tu interes

Comment: Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta para añadir esto último. Quien pretenda responderte no va a leerse todos los comentarios por si añaden algo util... esa persona espera que la pregunta sea autocontenida y completa. Por cierto, para referirte a alguien en especial usa '@'. Así le aparecerá un aviso indicándole la existencia del comentario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes al usar `cons` es que se acaba invocando esta implementación:

```
template < size_t N, typename CONTAINER, typename ERR = Error_UNDEFINED_TYPE >
struct typeat
{ 
  typedef ERR type;
};
```

Y de ahí que siempre recibas el error que comentas. Tienes un error de concepto. Las plantillas que tienes al principio esperan recibir una secuencia tal que:

```
typepair<float,typepair<float,typepair<int,empty>>>
```

En vez de lo que estás facilitando actualmente:

```
cons<float,float,int,empty>
```

Con lo que la línea en cuestión quedaría así:

```
typedef typename typeat<1,typepair<float,typepair<float,typepair<int,empty>>>>::type final;
```

Con esto ya el programa debería compilar. Si quisieses usar `cons` tendrías que realizar algunos cambios. Lo primero necesitas una estructura que permita convertir `Args...` en `typepair<T1,typepair<T2,...>>`:

```
template<typename ...Args>
struct pack;

template< typename T1, typename T2 >
struct pack<T1,T2>
{
  typedef typepair<T1,T2> type;
};

template < typename T1, typename ...Args >
struct pack<T1,Args...>
{
  typedef typename pack<Args...>::type nestedPair;
  typedef typepair<T1,nestedPair> type;
};
```

Y ahora solo falta modificar `const`:

```
template <typename ...Args >
struct cons 
{ 
  typedef typename pack<Args...>::type type; 
};
```

Y ahora la prueba de fuego:

```
typedef cons<float,float,int,empty> mio_t; 
typedef typename  typeat<1,mio_t::type>::type final;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_floating_point<final>::value << std::endl;
```

Comment: Muuuchismas gracias por la respuesta,pues el libro esta mal autodocumentado va demasiado al grano sin ejemplos practicos

Comment: @FJsanto Las plantillas no son algo trivial y cuesta cogerles el punto. Por otro lado, si la respuesta soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla como solución. Con ello aportas tu granito de arena en SO.